# How to improve igraph single_paths calculation efficiency

Tags: r, performance, igraph, memory-efficient, network-analysis

I'm using the function `all_simple_paths` from the `igraph` R package: (1) to generate the list of all simple paths in networks (object `List_paths_Mp`); and (2) to calculate the total number of simple paths (object `n_paths`).

I'm using the function in the form:

```
pathsMp <- unlist(lapply(V(graphMp), function(x)all_simple_paths(graphMp, from = x)), recursive =FALSE)

List_paths_Mp <- lapply(1:length(pathsMp), function(x)as_ids(pathsMp[[x]]))

n_paths<-length(List_paths_Mp)
```

Where:
  `Mp` is a square matrix with either `1` or `0` values, and `graphMp` is the `igraph` graph objected obtained through the function `graph_from_adjacency_matrix`.

The function does what I need, but with the increase in the number of variables and interactions the processing time to identify and store the different `single paths` in the network grows too much and it takes very long to get the results.

In particular, using a network with 11 variables and 60 interactions, there is a total of `146338` possible simple paths. And this already takes a long time to compute. Using a bigger network, with 13 variables and 91 interactions, causes the program to take even longer times to process (after 2 hours the function still didn't run its course, and when called to stop it crashed R).

Is there a way to increase the efficiency of the task (i.e. to get results in a faster way)? Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem and found a solution? And, I know, I could use a CPU with higher processing power, but the point is to have the function to run efficiently (as much as possible) in a normal personal computer.

Edit: here I do the calculations from the graph object, but if someone else has any idea of doing the same from the adjacency matrix, I would welcome it too!

Comment: If all you want is the total number of simple paths in a graph, these posts may provide some insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92555/counting-the-number-of-paths-on-a-graph or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97789/total-number-of-linear-paths-from-any-vertex-to-any-other-in-an-undirected-graph

Comment: @emilliman5 the thing is, I don't use this process just to get the number of total single paths, but to also obtain a list of all paths with the description of each node involved by order. The actual problem in the efficiency here seems to be the identification and storage of those paths.

Comment: If you need all the paths then you are SOL; as you add vertices the number of paths grows exponentially (memory footprint). Furthermore, since you want all paths you have to search the graph exhaustively which so execution time grows exponentially as well.

Comment: @emilliman5 yeah, that seems to be the very problem. That's why I was looking if someone else has any idea of how to improve this, even if just slightly. And of course, I don't need to be from a graph, can be directly from the adjacency matrix!